# Lightroom plugin does not show sectionsForBottomOfDialog on Windows

Tags: plugins, lua, sdk, lightroom

I have a lightroom plugin that works perfect on MacOSX, but on Windows the sectionsForBottomOfDialog does not show if there is something after the —— Camera —-.

I see that other plugin have sectionsForBottom with files and buttons, but I can’t find the problem. No errors
Been looking in code of other plugins, but my setup seems correct

Pluginprovider

```
function pluginInfoProvider.sectionsForBottomOfDialog(f, propertyTable )
return {
    {
        title = "Configuration",
        bind_to_object = propertyTable,

        f:view {
            fill_horizontal = 1,
            spacing = f:control_spacing(),
            font            = "<system>",
            ConfigDialogs.DefaultDirectories(f, propertyTable),
            ConfigDialogs.CameraFilm(f, propertyTable),
        }
    },
}
end
```

The code

```
function ConfigDialogs.CameraFilm(f, propertyTable)
return
    f:group_box {
        title   = 'Adding Camera and Film',
        fill_horizontal = 1,    
        --------- Camera --------
        f:row { 
            f:static_text {
                title           = "Camera Name:",
                alignment       = "left",
                width_in_chars  = "11",  
            }, 
            f:edit_field {
                alignment       = "left", 
                width_in_chars  = 20, 
                immediate = true, 
                value           = bind "CameraName",        
            },….
```

Everything from f:row seems to fail

My sectionsForTopOfDialog are working (if the other is disabled)

```
function pluginInfoProvider.sectionsForTopOfDialog( f, propertyTable )
return {
    {
        title = "Analoge Fotografie",
        f:view {
            fill_horizontal = 1,
            spacing = f:control_spacing(),
            font            = "<system>",
            ConfigDialogs.Information(f, propertyTable)
        }
    },
}
end
```

The code

```
function ConfigDialogs.Information(f, propertyTable)
return
    f:row {
        spacing = f:control_spacing(),
        f:static_text {
            title = "bla bla bla",
        },
    }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the issue:

```
width_in_chars  = "11",
```

This must be a numeric value, not a string! Or even better:

```
width = LrView.share 'labelWidth',
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, quite stupid of me. It was the only one.
The reason for using this was for alignment.
Going to open a bug ticket at Adobe, On MacOSX it works, but should not.